# ASP.net logging errors that occur on different pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, logging

How would i go about to do this?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            doSomething();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Here i would like to know that the page is "Problem.aspx"
            // and that it was caused from the doSomething() function
        }
    }

    private void doSomething()
    {
        logToSomething();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using this little class to log errors, have a look on how i get the page and the function(Stacktrace):

```
public static class ErrorLog
{
    public static void WriteError(Exception ex)
    {
        try {
            string path = "~/error/logs/" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + ".txt";
            if ((!System.IO.File.Exists(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)))) {
                System.IO.File.Create(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path)).Close();
            }
            using (System.IO.StreamWriter w = System.IO.File.AppendText(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(path))) {
                w.WriteLine(System.Environment.NewLine + "Log Entry : {0}", System.DateTime.Now.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                var page = VirtualPathUtility.GetFileName(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath);
                w.WriteLine("Error in: " +  page);
                string message = "Message: " + ex.Message;
                w.WriteLine(message);
                string stack = "StackTrace: " + ex.StackTrace;
                w.WriteLine(stack);
                w.WriteLine("__________________________");
                w.Flush();
                w.Close();
            }
        } catch (Exception writeLogException) {
            try {
                WriteError(writeLogException);
            } catch (Exception innerEx) {
                //ignore
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It's entirely sufficient for me.

*Note: converted from VB.NET, hence untested*

Comment: So much unnecessary code, when you can set up Enterprise Library Logging block and it's all done for you.

Answer (score 1):

Exception object has a [stack trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.stacktrace%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) property, which tells you exactly where the error took place.

Also, check out [Microsoft Enterprise Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff632023.aspx) (more specifically the Logging Block).

The logged errors provide a stack trace, among other things, letting you know exactly where the error occurred.

Comment: `Elmah` available from nuget is a part of the mentioned library and rocks when it comes to error handling.

Answer (score 0):

You can determine all of that by parsing  the Exception message.

Look at your message and use a regex to extract the information you need.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that you may want to look into is ELMAH ( Error Logging Modules and Handlers for ASP.NET ) http://code.google.com/p/elmah/ .  I guess it really depends on what your specific needs are.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**log4net**](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/index.html), for logging the error messages. For help look at these [article 1](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/log4net.aspx) and [article 2](http://www.codemyne.net/%28S%28zwaehuenlz4iprygrl0xwjft%29%29/articles/using-log4net-in-asp-net-website.aspx?visitid=38&type=2).

Answer (score 0):

Whatever logging method you use, do something like this.(Hand typed may not compile)

```
try
{
  DoignStuff();
}
catch( Exception ex)
{
Trace.WriteLine( "Exception in <Page Name>  while calling DoingStuff() Ex:"+ ex.ToString() );
}
```

It will start with the page name & method (which is redundant, but makes life easier)
then it will convert the EX to a string which shows call stack and all kinds fo other good stuff and put it in the log file

Note: you have to Type the name of the page in the place of `<Page Name>` .

Log4Net and Elmah are great to make life easier too.